# Point to raster conversion: point not in the center of raster cell

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, raster-to-point

I created a point dataset by adding a x/y coordinates from an Excel table. Here's my point shapefile:

[image]

I am converting it to a raster using cell size of 1 using the `point to raster` in `Conversion Tools`. I do not understand why the points are not located in the center of each raster cell. In fact for some cells (on the lower left hand side), the points are in the center while for some it is not. I think this is also leading to the white strip in the middle.

Why are the points not in the center of the raster cells, and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this thread from GeoNet might help: [point to raster point is not in the center of the created cell](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/176074)

Comment: I think this is the expected result but you'd think there'd be more thorough documentation on the subject.

Comment: How far between each point?

Comment: How do I calculate that?

Answer (score 1):

So I tried a different method which solved my problem. Since my issue had to do more with the improving the display, this works for me.

I simply used `square2` as symbol of size 32 instead of using `point` as symbol

[image]

and change the `colour` to `no colour` for the boundaries. This works fine for me.

[image]

Comment: Where is raster in this solution?

Comment: there is no raster. Since I just wanted to display my grids, this works fine for me.

Comment: @user53020 This doesn't provide an answer to the question.  If your question was just "how do I get it to look like a raster" then this might be closer to answering it.